# Parsing dates in R with weird format

Tags: r, date, parsing

Hi guys I have a list of dates with this weird format : X1.22.20 X1.23.20 (month/day/year).
and I would like to have "2020-06-11" ('%d %b %Y').
I tried this:

```
> min.date <- min(dates)
> max.date <- max(dates)
> min.date.txt <- min.date %>% format('%d %b %Y')
> max.date.txt <- max.date %>% format('%d %b %Y') %>% paste('UTC')
> min.date
[1] "2002-10-10"
```

And the value is crazy because I know for sure that there are not 2002 int his data.
Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the question is how to convert the input `x` shown below to `Date` class use `as.Date` with a format that corresponds to the input so it must start with X, have dots where the input has dots, etc.  Look at `?strptime` for documentation on the percent codes.

```
x <- c("X1.22.20", "X1.23.20") # input

as.Date(x, format = "X%m.%d.%y")
## [1] "2020-01-22" "2020-01-23"
```

Note that if you got those dates like this:

```
Lines <- "1.22.20 1.23.20
1 2
3 4"
read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
##   X1.22.20 X1.23.20
## 1        1        2
## 2        3        4
```

then the X can be avoided using `check.names = FALSE` as follows:

```
read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)
##   1.22.20 1.23.20
## 1       1       2
## 2       3       4
```